# Django messages with javascript fetch() API and redirect

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am doing a request with the `fetch()` API to a django view, which will set a message with the `messages` app and redirect the request. I can capture the redirect with `response.redirected` and the `messages`-cookie is set, but when i do the redirect with `location.replace`, the messages get lost.

How do i pass on the messages from the original response?

The django view:

```py
def add(request):

    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("not post")

    pproject = request.POST['pproject']

    print("pproject:", pproject)

    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Test.")
    return redirect("project_detail")
```

my `urls.py`:

```py
    path('project/add/', views_project.add, name='project_add'),
```

and in my template (javascript):

```js
var csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);

const form = new FormData();

form.append("pproject", "{{ project.id }}");

const ops = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: form,
    credentials: "same-origin"
};

const req = new Request("{% url 'project_add' %}");

fetch(req, ops)
.then((response) => {
    if (response.redirected) {
        console.log("response redirect:", response);

        window.location.replace(response.url);
        return false;

    } else if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    } else {
        return response.json(); // Parse JSON response
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def add(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("not post")
    
    pproject = request.POST['pproject']
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Test.")
    
    # Construct the redirect URL with messages as query parameters
    redirect_url = reverse("project_detail") + "?message=test"

    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

> JavaScript

```
fetch(req, ops)
.then((response) => {
    if (response.redirected) {
        const url = new URL(response.url);
        const message = url.searchParams.get("message");
        
        if (message) {
            // Display the message
            console.log("Received message:", message);
        }

        window.location.replace(response.url);
        return false;
    } else if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    } else {
        return response.json(); // Parse JSON response
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not to receive the message, but to pass it on to `window.location.replace(response.url);`